# Can the IAR command line tool "iarbuild" do a build all?

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, iar

From the IAR command line, it's easy to build a particular configuration, and obviously, if I want to mimic the "build all" behavior I just run my own batch file with the configs I want.

**How do I handle the case where I want to build all configs, but I don't know in advance what configurations are available?**

Using Jenkins, for instance, if a developer adds a configuration in the IAR IDE, it won't be included in a build until the Jenkins scripts are manually updated.  I just want Jenkins to build all the configurations without caring what they are called.  In the IAR GUI for setting up batches, there is an option to rebuild all so there must be something somewhere.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `*` as configuration name to build everything, like this:

```
c:\> iarbuild myproject.ewp -build *
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution I've implemented years ago for this problem was to read the configuration names from the .ewp file and use them for the build.

Regards
Yves